# Prompt a user and wait for response

Tags: gnuwin32, coreutils

In GNUwin32 or UnxUtils, is there a way to prompt a user to "Press enter to continue" and wait for the enter key, such as the unix 'read' command. I used to have an old command 'ask' that would do something similar.

Comment: What's wrong with using `pause`?

Comment: Thank you, that works fine.
Its been years since I used batch files and forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with standard windows command `pause`. But it waits for any key to be pressed, not only `Enter`.